# C # calling generic methods mutiple times with different types

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to store different types (names of types) in a List (or dictionary or tuples) and iterate the list to call a generic method for each item in the list ?

Comment: it should be possible yes, can you update the question with some code example so we can understand better what you are trying to acheive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of `System.Type` which stores all the different types you want to call the generic method with.

The answer can change based on your exact requirements, but assuming you are trying to call a public method for an instance of a class, you can do something like the following:

```
var types = new List<System.Type>(); // store all types in this

var genericMethod = instanceOfClassWithGenericMethod.GetType().GetMethod("MethodNameHere"); // you can use `nameof` for method name

foreach (var type in types)
{
    var genericMethodWithType = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
    genericMethodWithType.Invoke(instanceOfClassWithGenericMethod, null);
}
```